# lvalue required as left operand of assignment -error in ?: in C

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, lvalue

why does `a<=20? b=10 : c=30;` give lvalue error?

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

is it because b=10 and c=30 are statements and not expressions?

Answer (score 6):

It is because conditional operator has higher precedence than assignment operator and the expression is interpreted as

```
((a<=20)? (b=10) : c)=30;
```

What is returned from conditional operator is not a lvalue ([N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf)6.5.15, footnote 110), so the program will emit compile error.

You can use parentheses to overcome this problem of precedence.

```
a<=20? (b=10) : (c=30);
```

Using normal `if` statement should be better unless you have some reasons like:

- Doing code golf
- Trying to make your program hard to read
- Want to use what is returned from the expression

```
if (a <= 20) {
    b = 10;
} else {
    c = 30;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing parentheses around assignments.

This compiles and runs correctly:

```
int a = 20, b = -1, c = -1;
a<=20? (b=10) : (c=30);
printf("b=%d, c=%d\n", b, c);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Xh3fma)

**Note:** It goes without saying that such (mis)use of ternary operator has negative impact on readability of your code, and should be avoided in favor of a regular `if` statement.